# Auto boot up Compute engine

Tags: google-app-engine, google-compute-engine, google-cloud-platform

I want a compute engine to boot up at a particular time everyday, perform a task and then self shut down.

I also have a Google App Engine continuously running, if that can be of any help!

Comment: what have yiu tried? look at the compute engine api

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use a [cron job on AppEngine](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/config/cron) and call the [Compute Engine API](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/reference/latest/instances/start) to start your instance.